# No property findOne() found for type class User

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have searched many pages but didnt found the answer so i paste the whole code.I am testing the testclass and getting the error like "Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.home.mysystem.entity.User org.home.mysystem.repository.UserRepository.findOne(java.lang.String)! No property findOne found for type User!". Please someone help me

Role.java

```
package org.home.mysystem.entity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<User> users;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Role(String name, List<User> users) {
        this.name = name;
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Task.java

```
package org.home.mysystem.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String date;
    @NotEmpty
    private String startTime;
    @NotEmpty
    private String stopTime;
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(length=1000)
    private String description;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_EMAIL")
    private User user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }
    public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }
    public String getStopTime() {
        return stopTime;
    }
    public void setStopTime(String stopTime) {
        this.stopTime = stopTime;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Task(String date, String startTime, String stopTime, String description, User user) {
        this.date = date;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.stopTime = stopTime;
        this.description = description;
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Task(String date, String startTime, String stopTime, String description) {
        this.date = date;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.stopTime = stopTime;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Task() {
    }



}
```

User.java

```
package org.home.mysystem.entity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    @Size(min = 4)
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Task> tasks;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES", joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name = "USER_EMAIL", referencedColumnName = "email") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_NAME", referencedColumnName = "name") })
    private List<Role> roles;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Task> gettasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void settasks(List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User(String email, String name, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {

    }

}
```

RoleRepository.java

```
    package org.home.mysystem.repository;

    import org.home.mysystem.entity.Role;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

    public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, String> {

    }
```

TaskRepository.java

```
 public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {

        List<Task> findByUser(User user);

    }
```

UserRepository.java

```
package org.home.mysystem.repository;

import org.home.mysystem.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,String> {

    User findOne(final String email);

}
```

TaskService.java

```
 package org.home.mysystem.service;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.home.mysystem.entity.Role;
    import org.home.mysystem.entity.Task;
    import org.home.mysystem.entity.User;
    import org.home.mysystem.repository.TaskRepository;
    import org.home.mysystem.repository.UserRepository;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;



    @Service
    public class TaskService {

        @Autowired
        private TaskRepository taskRepository;

        public void addTask(Task task, User user) {
            task.setUser(user);
            taskRepository.save(task);
        }

        public List<Task>  findUserTask(User user){

            return taskRepository.findByUser(user);
        }
    }
```

UserService.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.home.mysystem.entity.Role;
import org.home.mysystem.entity.User;
import org.home.mysystem.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;



@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public void createUser(User user) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder=new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        Role userRole=new Role("USER");
        List<Role> roles=new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add(userRole);
        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public void createAdmin(User user) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder=new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        Role userRole=new Role("ADMIN");
        List<Role> roles=new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add(userRole);
        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public User findOne(String email) {
        return userRepository.findOne(email);
    }
}
```

MyApplicationTest.java

```
package org.home.mysystem;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.util.List;

import org.home.mysystem.entity.Task;
import org.home.mysystem.entity.User;
import org.home.mysystem.service.TaskService;
import org.home.mysystem.service.UserService;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MySystemApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;

    @Before
    public void initDb() {
      {
          User newUser = new User("testUser@mail.com", "testUser", "123456");
          userService.createUser(newUser); 
      }
      {
          User newUser = new User("testAdmin@mail.com", "testAdmin", "123456");
          userService.createUser(newUser); 
      }

      Task userTask = new Task("03/01/2018", "00:11", "11:00", "You need to work today");
      User user = userService.findOne("testUser@mail.com");
      taskService.addTask(userTask, user);  

    }

    @Test
    public void testUser() {
        User user=userService.findOne("testUser@mail.com");
        assertNotNull(user);
        User admin=userService.findOne("testAdmin@mail.com");
        assertEquals(admin.getEmail(),"testAdmin@mail.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void testTask() {
        User user=userService.findOne("testUser@mail.com");
        List<Task> task=taskService.findUserTask(user);
        assertNotNull(task);
    }

    }
```

Comment: What in the spring-data-jpa makes you think that findOne() is a valid method name? What query should that method generate?

Comment: it should generate an object of class User

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Please point, in the spring-data-jpa documentation, where you find that findOne() was a valid query method, and what it's supposed to do. (Hint: as the error message says, it's not a valid query method. So, read the documentation to find what valid query method you can define instead. Also read the documentation of JpaRepository, so that you realize that it **already** has a method allowing to find an entity by its ID).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that Spring is expecting something else as you are giving it.

`findOne` is by default defined to take an ID (primary key) to load the entity by. So it expects a `long` or `Long` (as far as I know). It takes the name of the parameter given (email) and is searching for an ID with that name and that simply doesn't add up.

If you want to search by an email or other field that has been defined by you, you need to use the following syntax:

**Example 1**

Example field to search by: `email`

Method in repository:
`User findByEmail(String email)`

**Example 2**

Example field to search by: `username`

Method in repository:
`User findByUsername(String username)`

I hope this helps!

Comment: you r genious suprebbbbbb

Comment: thnk u god bless you

Comment: You are **way** overdoing your gratitude, but you are very welcome! Glad that it worked. For the future, I'd recommend consulting the documentation first, as it is clearly defined there.

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot! Why didn't I see this answer last week!